# Am I understanding Firebase Analytics correctly?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics, ionic5

My goal is to integrate Ionic5(based on Angular) with Firebase analytics. I need to do it for Android, IOS and web.

The thing is that what works for IOS and Android - does not work for web.

So, my current solution - for mobile:

```
import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics/ngx';
```

and then use it to log events, ect:

```
this.fa.logEvent(name, properties);
```

And if the user is from web (tried the same as for mobile - but it did not work):

```
import 'firebase/analytics';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

and log events -         firebase.analytics().logEvent(name, properties);
```

My question here:
Do I understand it correctly?
Should I have different ways of implementation for web and mobile for all methods (like on example)?
Ex.

```
In constructor    (private fa: FirebaseAnalytics)

  logEvent(name: string, properties: LogEventPropertiesModel): void {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  if (this.isDesktop()) {
    firebase.analytics().logEvent(name, properties); // Ex: "select_content", {content_type: "page_view"}
  } else {
    this.fa.logEvent(name, properties); // Ex: "select_content", {content_type: "page_view"}
  }
  //
});
```

}

Comment: "Did not work" in what way? Do you get errors?

Comment: @GuyIncognito I tried checking events in Debug mode - and nothing was going to the Firebase - my events were not logging. But once I tried  firebase.analytics().logEvent(name, properties); it started showing up and was working pretty fine.

Comment: Why are you using Firebase for web?

Comment: @Tico Some users will prefer it  (not my decision thought).  Firebase is available for web  as well. I am just trying to understand how to combine it all - IOS, Android and Web analytics.

Comment: I see. What I'd do -- and done in the past -- is use Firebase for Apps and Google Analytics for Web. Unless you're talking about a WebView, then it's a whole other thing. It's been a while since I've worked with Analytics.

Comment: @Tico It was added not so long ago - https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web

Comment: I was checking it out. Google at some point was thinking about merging everything to Firebase, I don't know why, it's so bad compared to GA. Anyway... You can do this distinction, then. Keep in mind that FB Web events won't show in DebugView. You'll need to download an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?authuser=0) according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview?authuser=0#web)

Comment: @Tico Thnaks) Used that to check. Just strange for me - why 2 different implementations for mobile and web. Why they did not combine it. Suppose - they have theirs reasonings.

Comment: [I think they did 'merge' it](https://www.cardinalpath.com/blog/google-to-sunset-support-for-google-analytics-services-sdk-transitions-mobile-analytics-to-firebase). I remember getting the email at work (big telco), we had the 360 suite, so we had some extra time to migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct and in line with current [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics)

Firebase.Analytics leverages native implementations with iOS/Android and JS implementation for web.

In theory you could just stick to one implementation being javascript which in case of Ionic would work across all platforms (due to web-view or browser), but native implementations allow you not to worry about another javascript code blocking main thread etc (so mostly performance reasons).